# rails3.1 ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/images/up_arrow.gif"):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, image, get, routes

My stylesheet has:
`.asc {
    font-size: 2em;
  background-image: url(/images/up_arrow.gif);
}`
`.desc {
  background-image: url(/images/down_arrow.gif);
}`

The font-size works but the background image (arrow) doesn't.
I get `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/images/up_arrow.gif"):`

I tried lots of things in routes but nothing worked.[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally found that I needed to do the new precompile of assets step.
'I shoulda read the manual'

Compiled assets are put in public/assets directory by default (the destination is defined in `config.assets.prefix)`.

To create compiled versions of your assets use `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

If you don't have write access for the production file system, use this task locally and then copy the compiled asset files.

The asset compilation process:

**1.** Concatenates & compresses all JavaScript files into one master. [Uglifier](https://github.com/lautis/uglifier) is the default for the process.
 **2** Compresses (minifies) all CSS files into one master .css file. CSS is compressed by [yui](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/css.html) by default.
 **3.** Allows for high level languages like coffeescript to use the assets.

Note: It is possible (though not a great idea) to disable the asset pipeline by changing config/application.rb and set
`config.assets.enabled = false`

You can skip the asset pipeline when creating a new application with the `—skip-sprockets option`, e.g. `rails new appname --skip-sprockets`

You can also set `config.assets.compile = true` This way the assets are only compiled when a request for them is made.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
.asc { font-size: 2em; background-image: url(/assets/up_arrow.gif); }
.desc { background-image: url(/assets/down_arrow.gif); }
```

That's how I do it in a 3.1 app I'm working on. Your `/images` is probably mapped to `app/public/images`.

Answer (score 2):

Dumb question perhaps, but are you positive that `/images/up_arrow.gif` exists?

When you 404 on an public asset in it just falls through to the rails router.  It's not really a routing problem; you just get a routing error because there are no routes defined for static assets.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue with Rails 3.2.13.

Solution was to modify the css to this:

```
.asc { font-size: 2em; background-image: url(up_arrow.gif); }
.desc { background-image: url(down_arrow.gif); }
```